# MongoDB data files created in wrong directory while changing oplog size

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to change oplog size. Therefore I'm following the instructions in http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/change-oplog-size/ However when I run the command

```
db.runCommand( { create: "oplog.rs", capped: true, size: (20 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) } )
```

It creates the data files(`local.0`, `local.[1-20]` and `local.ns`) under `/data/db` instead of `/data/db/local`

Do you have any idea what may be missing?

Edit: It actually creates `local.0` and `local.ns` when I started the mongodb in the standalone mode.

```
mongod --port 37017 &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of your files in MongoDB 2.4 will be affected by the [directoryperdb](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--directoryperdb) setting in your MongoDB configuration file:

Run the command below to see if you have set the flag directoryperdb in your configuration file.

`mongo --port 27017 admin`

`db.adminCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1});`

But, be careful, you cannot change this setting after you have already loaded customer data in your system.

Changing this setting after MongoDB has data will give you the "impression" that your data has been lost. MongoDB will not find the files in the "expected" path, and your queries will not work as expected.

Bottom line:

- If you start MongoDB without the directoryperdb setting, you must not
  add it later.
- If you start MongoDB with the directoryperdb setting,
  you must not remove it later.

Comment: directoryperdb is set to true in my configuration file. Actually the dbs previously created have their own directories and when I start my mongo instance as a replica, it does not create the files in /data/db directory. It only creates when i try to start the server in standalone mode.

Comment: Do you have 2 config files? Or do you start MongoDB as a standalone by passing arguments in the command line? Based on your description when you start as a standalone directoryperdb is not being set.  running db.adminCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1}); will confirm

Comment: you are right, I was assuming server gets the config file. Now I supply the config file and everything is just fine. Thanks!